# Blender syncs objects unexpectedly fast, one instance only

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So I have rendered an animation and each frame had taken about 55-60seconds.
Of that time 13-16seconds was the scene setup (sync objects etc)
When it syncs objects it usually does 2-3 objects looks as if the program freezes (blue spinning mouse curser) then 7-8seconds later resumes. This happens for basically any file I'm working on. And have seen this pause across multiple platforms. Intel and amd.

I don’t know if the blender is doing stuff or having a moment of blah…

I was fiddling with my blender file and got the scene setup to 5-6 seconds. As if that whole 7-8seconds delay disappeared!!!
Which makes me think something is wrong with blender

I don’t know what I did? And cannot replicate the faster performance!!

When my blend file opens I usually have *Simplify* enabled subdivision set to 1, and the A.O. bounce count to 3max.
As for other settings. In my blend I didn’t touch them in that one instance it worked fast!

I was only changing values in the *Simplify* section…
Then noticed one render finished well 8 seconds faster!
to which I actually eventually changed the settings back to what they were as if the blender file was just opened… and the changes were evident as for better quality renders… only blender was no longer having that 7-8second timeout!

My sys spec.
Ryzen 1600 @ 3.95 GHZ
16GB DDR4 @ 2400
Windows 10 Pro
GTX 780ti 3GB + 2x GTX 1060 3GB

I hope someone here knows what is going on

Comment: So far your question seems to be like "I did something I didn't notice which sped up the render, tell me what could that be". Rendering performance depends on huge amount of factors, not only on hardware. Scene is what really matters here and there's no info about that.

Comment: The reason I wrote this was because this oddly seems like a bug. Being that messing around with simplify speed up heaps but cannot reproduce.

Comment: I found that turning simplify on and off a bunch of times fixed it for me. I turned it on render, cancel render when the blocks appear, then turn simplify off and render, cancel. I repeat this until it's faster.. from 14 sec to start rendering down to 5! Now I'm checking other files to see if this trick works for other files